# Micro-B USB male to 2x Micro-B USB female Y splitter adapter

Tags: usb, cables, adapter, mobile, hdmi

I'm looking for the above mentioned splitter.
It's like [this](http://i.ebayimg.com/t/HDMI-Male-Dual-HDMI-Female-1-2-Way-Y-Splitter-Gold-Cable-Adapter-HD-TV-/00/s/NTAwWDUwMA==/%24T2eC16RHJIIE9qTYKDJlBQ!1IBcIRQ~~60_12.JPG), but Micro-B USB
and like [this](http://i.ebayimg.com/t/NEW-Genuine-Samsung-micro-USB-6-Dual-Male-Y-Adapter-Splitter-Original-/20/!CFc2yNgBGk~%24%28KGrHqN,!lEE1F+%29i10DBNVGVJyWHw~~_12.JPG), but reverse the male/female.

By the way, I was able to use my Samsung Galaxy S3 phone with the Samsung MHL Micro-B USB to HDMI adapter for TV (with Micro-B USB additional power), and with Micro-B USB on-the-go adapter for USB keyboard and USB-wireless mouse (with a 1:4 USB hub).
I want these three stuff to be connected at the same time, hence the splitter adapter required. I'm not sure if it's even possible, due to power, bus and other limitations I'm not aware of.

Comment: Also I'm not sure this is the right forum to ask this, so any pointer is appreciated.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Electronics.Stackexchange! This is a site about electronic design, while your question regards consumer devices. You can try on  Super User, but it's also a shopping question and therefore too localized to be useful to others.

Comment: You are right and not, it's about electronic connectivity, because I don't know that what I'm looking for exists or not, and the answer I got is perfect and I wouldn't have gotten that on other forums, I think. Also I think we can agree on that ebay and amazon are not local (maybe question of price), my friend who creates gizmos orders a lot from these.

Comment: I'm glad that you found a solution, but actually consumer devices like this are off topic here. We treat electronic design, and shopping questions are discouraged because they tend to become obsolete quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HDMI output is via the [Mobile High-Definition Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_High-Definition_Link) capability of your phone's port.  This port is **not** a normal Micro-B USB port.  On most phones, it is a 5 pin connector that is the same shape as (and can be used as) a Micro-B USB, but when you're doing HDMI output, it's not speaking the normal USB protocol and so you can't do both simultaneously.

**However**, the Samsung Galaxy S III uses a new 11-pin MHL connector that can do both.  See [this news article](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2012/06/29/galaxy-s-iii-new-mhl-connector-also-enables-usb-on-go/) for some info on that.  But it seems that the appropriate adapters [aren't really available](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1836822) yet.  I don't think this is something you can easily make on your own.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers, really helpful.
Based on this I think it's an urban legend that Samsung made the connector incompatible on purpose, they are just using something new which is not 100% backwards compatible. (Like cannot connect SATA with IDE cable).